# Yii1 action doesn't get $_POST from postman

Tags: php, rest, yii, postman, yii-components

I'm using Yii 1, and testing an API i'm working on, and when i POST to this URL

`https://blabla.com/products/report/notification`

I get nothing on [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d5vD.png)

My Filters

```
public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }
```

My action is

```
public function actionnotification() {

        print_r($_POST);
        // print_r(Yii::app()->request->getPost('report_id')); //this didn't work either
        die;
}
```

the URL is correct, and if i `echo 'hi';` in the action above, it does echo hi.

and my rules are

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('notification'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            );
     }
```

Here is my exported cURL from postman

```
curl -X POST \
  https://blabla.com/products/report/notification \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=puevhejh61fg4f0qtc52nbg3jm' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 4fb0526b-f26e-4802-bf13-8361f65a26af,b610902b-25f1-4eb9-9ce6-cfddec164788' \
  -H 'Referer: https://blabla.com/products/report/notification' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.18.0' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'report_id=123131231&status_id=1'
```

When i change it to a `params and GET` it works, but `POST, body x-www-form-urlencoded` and a `GET, body x-www-form-urlencoded` doesn't work, is there something I'm missing here? Thank you

Comment: Are you sending any actual POST parameters? What your postman screenshot shows, are headers only. So, where is the actual POST data?

Comment: @CBroe sorry i uploaded a new image. same result

Comment: It works changing to `GET`? Seems fishy. Can you export cURL from postman and paste here?

Comment: @Justinas params GET yes, but GET x-www-form-urlencoded doesn't work either

Comment: @Justinas updated questions with cURL

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the POST data in the body instead. I usually use Yii methods instead of $_POST or $_GET:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests

**Edit:**
Here's my postman configuration for sending POST requests
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAp2v.jpg)

**Edit2:**
In your config file, you should add to components/requests a property named enableCsrfValidation and set it to false. I'll leave you mine:

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => {key},
        'enableCsrfValidation' => false
    ],
...
```

Comment: i tried both `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `form-data`, still blank

Comment: I know it's a no-brainer, but are you changing the request method from GET to POST? (it happened to me before) like this https://imgur.com/rvbMlty

Comment: I've started a fresh project to test your issue, but I'm not being able to reproduce. Can you dump the $_REQUEST instead? I would like to see what's reaching the serverside. Also, do you have CSRF validation disabled in your project? The only way I'm getting an empty array as response, is when I'm not sending the POST data.

Comment: Does csrf need to be off for an API? If so how do I turn it off just for the api or how do I keep it on?

Comment: I had to deactivate it in order to be able to send POST requests through POSTMAN. I just edited my original answer with an example.